# Angular velocity in body frame to displacement in lab frame?

Tags: rotational-dynamics, reference-frames, rotation, rotational-kinematics, angular-velocity

For the case of a freely spinning symmetric top (no gravity), I derived the following equations, where $\omega_i$ is the angular velocity **about a body-fixed axis**:

$$ \omega_1 = w_1 \cos (w_3 t) $$
$$ \omega_2 = w_1 \sin (w_3 t) $$
$$ \omega_3 = w_3 $$

where $w_1, w_3$ are the initial values of angular velocity ($w_2 = 0$).

Now I want to convert these angular velocities into an angular displacement with respect to the lab frame. How would I do so? (I have a feeling that Euler angles may be useful, but I do not understand how to use them.)